# How to inject HTML when running Karma test in browsers?

Tags: karma-runner

I need to add some HTML tags to the Body when running test with Karma.

eg: `<object id='sefNNaviPlugin' classid='clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-NNAVI'></object>`

Here is my karma config: http://pastebin.com/5YsNpr1r

is there a way to add them by Karma configuration?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use `customContextFile` to replace the basic html page of karma with your html page.
like that:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    files: [ '**/*.spec.js'],
    customContextFile:path.resolve('index.tmpl.html'),
  })
}
```